# Probability m randomly selected Boolean n-vectors is likely to span the whole space

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra, quantum-computing

What probability of a set of m randomly selected Boolean n-vectors is likely to span the whole space, provided m = Ω(nlog 2n)?

I know probability at least 1/2 then m randomly selected Boolean n-vectors is likely to span the whole space. But i dont know prove that.